# HTML Color change, dependent upon MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, colors

So I am building a room selection system, using a quasi MVC model for it. I have a floor plan page with html radio button rooms, a php script that processes the selection, and acts as a confirmation page, and then the SQL connection upon confirmation that writes to the database. What I'm trying to do is make it so once a room is selected, after the room number is written to the Database, the background color on the floor plan page changes to show that the room is selected, I'm thinking simply changing it from Green to Red.

Any insight to offer?

Comment: Conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use PHP to Fetch the data from MySQL
2. Based on the MySQL data, Write if else to get the color string (red, blue) in a $variable
3. Use that in HTML code

Code:

```
<body bgcolor="<?php echo $variable; ?> ">
```

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii- for improving. I was not able to mark the line as code, don't know why. New to stackoverflow

Comment: You're welcome. I too don't understand why code doesn't show as code when using bullets/numbered lists. Some type of bug. My way around that is to either use `----` as a line seperator (`<hr>`), or just plain text.